# How to make custom changes in date and time differences?

Tags: php, datetime, echo, difference

I want to echo some date only when they are closer like.

I had created one script and in that I had used following code.

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$todaydate=$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expdate="2020-09-13 21:00:00";

function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
    $result = "";
    if ($interval->y) { $result .= $interval->format("%y years "); }
    if ($interval->m) { $result .= $interval->format("%m months "); }
    if ($interval->d) { $result .= $interval->format("%d days "); }
    if ($interval->h) { $result .= $interval->format("%h hours "); }
    if ($interval->i) { $result .= $interval->format("%i minutes "); }
    if ($interval->s) { $result .= $interval->format("%s seconds "); }

    return $result;
}

$exp_date = new DateTime($expdate);
$today_date = new DateTime($todaydate);

$difference = $exp_date->diff($today_date);

echo "Days left to expiry:".format_interval($difference)."</br>";
```

It gives (aprox result)

Days left to expiry: 4 years 10 months 18 days 8 hours 0 minutes 40 seconds

now I want to show this only when it is expiring in 2 months means 1 months 30 days or less ......

I tried

```
  if ("%m"<=1){
      echo "Days left to expiry:".format_interval($difference)."</br>";
  }
```

but it didn't worked?

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Carbon, it is really useful for date processing: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months is a little more difficult and would require additional logic, but you could base this on days which is provided by the `DateInterval` class.

You could change the logic like so:

```
// Average 60 days over 2 months
if($difference->days <= 60) {
    echo "Days left to expiry:".format_interval($difference)."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked... also how can I convert "2020-09-13 21:00:00" into 13 Sep. 2020 21:00:00 like this format? any option? 

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');

its not [working](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: @SirenBrown if you're looking to format the `$exp_date`, that object has a format method, i.e. `$exp_date->format('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');` - Results: https://3v4l.org/7HCSE

Documentation can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: I think the format you're looking for is https://3v4l.org/sPGaT which is `d M. Y H:i:s`

Answer (score 1):

@steadweb

```
<?php
  $expdate="2020-09-13 21:00:00";
  $exp_date = new DateTime($expdate);
  print $exp_date->format('d M. Y H:i:s');
?>
```

yes it worked :)